# python: gaierror [Error -2] Name or service not known sshTunnelForwarder

Tags: python, ssh-tunnel

Below code is giving the gaierror [Error -2] Name or service not known sshTunnelForwarder

```
self.server=sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder(
                        ('abc.int.net', 22),
                        ssh_username="sshuser",
                        ssh_password="sshpassword",
                        remote_bind_address=('remote.address.host', 4040)
                        )
```

It works fine in windows

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the local_bind_address parameter too. It is better to explicitly state which local port the remote port is being mapped to.

```
self.server=sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder(
                    ('abc.int.net', 22),
                    ssh_username="sshuser",
                    ssh_password="sshpassword",
                    remote_bind_address=('remote.address.host', 4040),
                    local_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 3331)
                    )
```